# Swift3 Protocol Delegate function never called

Tags: swift3, swift-protocols

I have a login view controller which is called by various other view controllers which need to check login status. They do this in the viewWillAppear() function. The login view controller has a navigation bar with a closeView() function to pop it when pressed.

In this function I call the delegate function to also close the presenting view controller but that controller again invokes the check auth function when it appears. My delegate function to close it never gets called. Is there any way I can achieve this? To be clear, if the user cancels the login by pressing the close button on the login controller I want its presenting view controller to also close.

The problem seems to be that the call to `checkAuth()` in `viewWillAppear()`  triggers before my delegate function gets called.

Here is my code.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UserCancelledLoginDelegate {

    var delegate : UserCancelledLoginDelegate?

-------

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)        
    callCheckAuth()  //loads login controller if not logged in 
}

-------------

func shouldCloseView() {

    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
}

----------

func callCheckAuth() {

// a utility to check auth which works

        if response?.statusCode == 200 {
           // do stuff                
        }
        else if response?.statusCode == 401 {

            self.loadSignInView()
```

}

---

```
protocol UserCancelledLoginDelegate {
    func shouldCloseView()
}


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : UserCancelledLoginDelegate?

----------

func closeView() {

   delegate?.shouldCloseView()        

  if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to **set** the delegate somewhere.

Comment: put this callCheckAuth method also

Comment: How do I set the delegate and where? I have another delegate which works and uses this same pattern but for a different purpose.

Comment: you need to set delegate on that method **loginlViewController.delegate = self**

Comment: Won't fix your issue, but you should really be using `weak var delegate` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @KKRocks - where? This causes a compiler error if I set it in MyViewController.

Comment: - Paulo  `weak may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types`

Comment: how to set you ?

Comment: in the class loginViewController = LoginViewController() and in viewDidLoad() I set loginViewController.delegate = self. It compiled but the function was not called as it loaded the login controller first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a delegate I found I can use this code to close a view controller and its parent.

```
    if let navController = self.navigationController, navController.viewControllers.count > 0 {

        let viewController = navController.viewControllers[navController.viewControllers.count - 3]

        navigationController!.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }
```